# mongoid: update nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, persistence

i am running into an issue with updates to nested attributes for referenced documents not being persisted

```
> u = User.first
 => #<User...
> u.changes
 => {} 
> u.profile.changes
 => {} 
> u.attributes = {:profile_attributes => {:weight => 8}}
 => {:profile_attributes=>{:weight=>8}} 
> u.changes
 => {} 
> u.profile.changes
 => {"weight"=>[14.0, 8.0]} 
> u.update
 => true 
> u.shipping_profile.changes
 => {"weight"=>[14.0, 8.0]}
```

update/update_attributes/save all do not persist the nested changes.
i have `attr_accessible :profile_attributes` declared in the user model.

what is needed for nested attributes to persist when the parent document is already persisted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out its a mongoid issue.  i submit a pull request with the failing test here https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/pull/978 for anyone else having the same issue.  im just manually saving/updating nested records until its resolved

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the following in your `User` class?

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
```

If you're missing that line, i'm pretty sure it will ignore all attempts to update nested records via the parent using `update_attributes`.